# PostgreSQL and JDBC Prepared Statement Caching

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I've been reading that some of the newer JDBC Connection Pools (like Tomcat) do not support client side statement pooling. I already read that this is because most JDBC drivers maintain their own statement cache. However, I do not see this happening for PostgreSQL.

Am I correct on this? If so should I be using a connection pool that CAN cache prepared statements in order to get the best batched insert performance?

Thanks

Comment: To get the best batch insert performance you should be using the `COPY` API, accessed via PgConnection. AFAIK PgJDBC doesn't maintain a "statement cache" and I'm not sure whether such a thing would be effective since every session has its own independent set of server side prepared statements. PgJDBC's statement batching is pretty useless at the moment, btw, it just sends them individually anyway.

Comment: Thanks Craig, unfortunately it is not that simple. This batch comes from JSON and is parsed into an object graph with various relationships using JPA. It's hard to sort out the various IDs to create the file to do a COPY with. FWIW, if you are even doing 20 of the same prepared statement there is quite a bit of value just preparing that statement once and reusing it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's JDBC connection pool provides a [StatementCache](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache). I don't know how to use it (with JPA) but it promises to "cache `PreparedStatement` and/or `CallableStatement` instances on a connection."

But for insert batches you probably don't need to re-use a `PreparedStatement`: you can use the `addBatch` method as shown in [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/). Odd thing is though, that the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) says that "this method cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`". I guess you'll have to try it out to find out if that is true and as Craig Ringer comments: "PgJDBC just sends them individually anyway".

As for performance: that breaks down in client, server and driver/network traffic. 
Database servers generally learn what queries to expect from connections (which is also why re-using connections via a connection pool is a good idea). I believe the PostgreSQL database server will start to remember queries from a connection once the same  query occurs more than 5 times. 

If the driver properly handles `PreparedStatement`s that are re-used by the client, the driver can decide to only send the new data and not the whole query. This can have a significant positive performance effect for insert statements (and I believe that, among others, the JDBC driver for SQL Server does this). 

If the client caches `PreparedStatement`s (e.g. statement is only closed when the connection that created it is closed) it will help in not executing the same code (also from the driver) again and again. I.e. less initialization time and less garbage collection.

As example for an alternative to Tomcat's JDBC connection pool: I have used [Yapool](http://yapool.googlecode.com/)'s `SimpleQueryCache` ([example](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/trunk/yapool/yapool-examples/src/main/java/nl/fw/yapool/examples/ExampleQueryCache.java)) with a MySQL database (and JDBC driver) in a little server component that fired about 15 different queries. During stress/load testing I was surprised by the relative low number for the maximum amount of connections required in the pool that did not impact the speed of the little server component (i.e. connections were borrowed from the pool for a relative short amount of time). So, at least in some situations, client side caching of statements can make a difference.

On a side node: if you use something like Hibernate a lot of optimalizations are done for you by Hibernate (under water) and there is a good chance that (statement) caching is already done for you.